# Force stop app installed by mod APK by Firebase

Tags: android, apk, sentry, firebase-remote-config

I have an app in PlayStore. Someone has modified the APK then used it in an illegal way. I have updated my app right after that so they can not modify the latest version anymore, but the previous one is still be shared publicly.

My app integrates Firebase (Remote Configs) and Sentry. Is there any way that I can force stop the old versions app via 2 platforms?

Answer (score 0):

Remote Config can only be used to control code that is already in the application. So if your old versions of the app had some logic like:

```
if (firebaseRemoteConfig.getBoolean("killswitch") === true) {
   throw new Exception("Error");
}
```

Then you can trigger that logic through Remote Config by setting the `killswitch` parameter to `true` for people on that specific version.

But if you don't have such code in the old versions of your app, or have no way to identify the old users of your app, there is not much Remote Config can do here to help.